# WP7 Changing 1 layout element based on another

Tags: windows-phone-7, css-selectors

Having no luck here trying to find a solution to this.

I've set up a looping selector based on this [guide.](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-LoopingSelector-in-depth--Part1-Visual-structure-and-API) (I also used the ListLoopingDataSource class in Part 2 in order to have strings in my looping list).

What I want to be able to do is then change another element (an image box/placeholder) on my layout, based on what is currently selected in the looping selector.

No real idea how to do this, the onSelectionChanged event is kind of abstracted and not really useful? I'm not sure how to programmatically change images either, it doesn't look like I can access a resource from the code base, only from the xaml.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I could do this by using binding.